# how can Linq have a table's fields selected dynamically by a variable?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a table as follows:

```
public class Report
{

      public int ReportId { get; set; }

      public string ReportItem { get; set; }

      public int RowN { get; set; }

      public decimal M00 { get; set; }

      public decimal M01 { get; set; }

      public decimal M02 { get; set; }

      public decimal M03 { get; set; }

      public decimal M04 { get; set; }

      public decimal M05 { get; set; }

      public decimal M06 { get; set; }

      public decimal M07 { get; set; }

      public decimal M08 { get; set; }

      public decimal M09 { get; set; }

      public decimal M10 { get; set; }

      public decimal M11 { get; set; }

      public decimal M12 { get; set; }
}
```

Each time the first 4 fields should be viewed and the 5th field to be viewed is the one selected from remaining 12 fields. The selected variable is transferred from the view page to the controller and then back to the view page through a ViewBage. I have solved the problem by jQuery Datatable. The key code line is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            var table = $('.table').dataTable();

            for (var i=4; i <= 15; ++ i)
            {
                table.fnSetColumnVis(i, false, false);
            }

            var i = @ViewBag.strMon;

            table.fnSetColumnVis(i, true, false);

        });

</script>
```

In the way, all of the 12 fields are hiden firstly and then one of them is selected by the variable to show.

But it is a satisfactory way, for each time when I make a new selection, all of 12 fields are shown in the view page and then 11s disappear slowly.

I have another idea to solve the problem. I have made another table as follows:

public class ReportView
    {

```
    public int ReportId { get; set; }

    public string ReportItem { get; set; }

    public int RowN { get; set; }

    public decimal M00 { get; set; }

    public decimal M99 { get; set; }

}
```

What I want to do is write the data from Report to ReportView in the Controller and then make the view page related with ReportView to show. But I do not know how to do it. If the table fields can be selected by a variable the problem will be solved, or the table can be returned by its column number. Any help? Thanks.

Comment: Can you condense the question to be clearer?

Comment: Thanks for your concern. To make it simpler, there are 16 fields (or columns) in the table one, but only 5 fields are viewed each time. The first 4s are seen always, and the 5th is selected by a variable from 12s. Table two for the viewModel is built, in which only 5 fields. How can I read data from Table One to Table Two by option of a variable.

Comment: some one gave a suggestion to write a stored procedure as follows:

Answer (score 1):

This seems like it has what you want.  You can construct LINQ using strings.

https://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library

[image]

Of course, you would use a dynamic select.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot get a satisfactory answer for my question. I think that I did not make myself understood fully. Now I solved the problem by using a stored procedure. I hope it helps to make my question clear and also it may help some others with the same problem. The procedure is follows:

```
USE [MvcAccDb]
GO

/****** Object:  StoredProcedure [dbo].[InsertDataIntoReportViews]    Script Date: 09/24/2017 19:13:23 ******/

SET ANSI_NULLS ON

GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      <Author,,Name>
-- Create date: <Create Date,,>
-- Description: <Description,,>
-- =============================================

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[InsertDataIntoReportViews] 
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
    ( @month nvarchar(2))

AS

BEGIN

    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;


    -- Insert statements for procedure here

    insert into ReportViews (ReportID, ReportItem, RowN, M00, M99)
    select [ReportID],
    [ReportItem],
    [RowN],
    [M00], 
    CASE 
    WHEN @month = '01' then M01  
    WHEN @month = '02' then M02 
    WHEN @month = '03' then M03
    WHEN @month = '04' then M04  
    WHEN @month = '05' then M05 
    WHEN @month = '06' then M06
    WHEN @month = '07' then M07  
    WHEN @month = '08' then M08 
    WHEN @month = '09' then M09
    WHEN @month = '10' then M10  
    WHEN @month = '11' then M11 
    WHEN @month = '12' then M12
    END AS M99    
    from Reports
    END
```